# Handling $interval.cancel using $scope.$watch doesnt work

Tags: angularjs

Below I handled a timer function with $interval and I want to cancel the timer when my flag is set as true , Actually my request has to run multiple times until my flag is set as true.This scenario is actually used for uploading file, I open export request for multiple times by clicking the export button , so by then my timer will be called and it will look for my `data.staus` is `complete` , until my status is complete it will run .Since I am using watch here , it only works for latest export request and the previous export request clicked doesn't call my stoptimer function.

```
  angular.module('timerApp', ['timerApp.controllers']);
  angular.module('timerApp.controllers', []).controller('timerController', ['$scope', '$interval',
      function($scope, $interval) {
        var timer;
        var time = 10;
        $scope.countdown = time;
        $scope.stopTimer = function() 
        {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
         };



 $scope.startTimer = function() {
  timer = $interval(function() {
  $scope.countdown--;
//res is response from my backend
   var data = res;
   if (data.status = "complete"){
      $scope.timerFlag = true;
     }
    }, 15000, time);
         timer.then(function() {
        $scope.countdown = time;
      });
    };

  }

$scope.$watch(){
if($scope.timerFlag == true){
 $scope.stopTimer();

}

}
]);
```